# post data using get (not post) method

Tags: asp.net, get

I have a Webform with masterpage(where the form tag is). Inside the content page I have a textbox and a submit button. I want to send the data to the next page using GET not POST. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it can apply to all pages:

```
<form method="get" ... >
    <!-- content here -->
</form>
```

If you want only for a single, simple page:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "NextPage.aspx?";
    url = url + "&MyTxt1=" + MyTxt1.Text;
    url = url + "&MyTxt2=" + MyTxt2.Text;
    url = url + "&MyTxt3=" + MyTxt3.Text;
    // etc.
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

If you want to control the method from the content page:

```
// on the master page
public class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    // replace form1 with the id of your form control
    // make sure the form tag has runat="server"
    public string Method
    {
        get { return form1.Method; }
        set { form1.Method = value; }
    }
    // ...
}

// on the content page
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // replace SiteMaster with class type of the master class
    ((SiteMaster)this.Master).Method = "get";
}
```

Comment: but the form tag is inside the masterpage

Comment: That's a different question.  Look up how to access a master page from within a page using the master page.  You should be able to find a simple answer from google for such a common need.